# escape with JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, escaping

I'm trying to apply a simple escaping process in javascript <-> php communication. I doesn't work... I'm not sure why.

here is some test code I wrote :

```
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        JSON.parse('[{"id":"43","english":"ar\"m","korean":"\ud314","date":"49 minute(s) ago."}]');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The escaped character is a double quote inside the word arm.
The error returned when opening the page is :

```
VM84:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 26
     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at test.html:11
(anonymous) @ test.html:11
```

Comment: It's not clear what the point of this experiment is. If you're having problems with JSON sent by the server, then the problem is there anwyay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you include a JSON string as a string in JavaScript, you have to **double** the backslashes, because backslash is a metacharacter in both the JavaScript and the JSON syntaxes.

```
    JSON.parse('[{"id":"43","english":"ar\\\"m","korean":"\\ud314","date":"49 minute(s) ago."}]');
```

For the `\"` it's necessary to use *three* `\` characters, so that when the JSON parser sees it you have `\"`.

Note that it is **not** necessary to have those extra `\` in the *actual* JSON that your server sends to the client (or that the client sends to the server).

Note that there are not too many good reasons for JSON text to be embedded in JavaScript source code as a JavaScript string constant. If you're building the JavaScript source as part of an HTML document using a server-side tool like PHP  (or pretty much anything), JSON can be dropped into JavaScript source as an ordinary JavaScript object initializer, without an extra layer of quotes to make it look like a JavaScript string constant.

Comment: Doesn't really work for me since I'm parsing  something coming from a db

Comment: @Antoine if you're getting a string from the server then you don't have the problem in the first place. This question is about a JSON string embedded *as a string* in JavaScript source code. That in itself is a pretty strange situation, since JSON syntax can be parsed as-is directly by the JavaScript parser, so there's generally no need for it to be in a JavaScript string constant at all.